# Visual Studio 2010 installation failed on windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Im trying to install VS2010 on my windows 7, i already installed VS2012 on the same machine but also need VS2010, so im installing it from my DVD  but im getting the below error while installing it nd the setup is not installing...

i don't understand what the error is about and how to resolve it..

```
 [12/14/13,21:22:15] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] CMsiComponent::Install()    expects the setup file for Microsoft Application Error Reporting, but the file is not available.
 [12/14/13,21:22:15] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in    ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
```

note:previously i installed vs2010 couple of times from the same dvd, but i formatted my system nd now when im trying to install it the setup fails

Comment: It is trying to find the install file for a sub-component but can't find it on the disk.  That DVD is only useful as a coaster, it is useless to get VS installed.

Comment: i have installed VS with it before couple of times,what is the problem now?.. so is it not possible to install with it?